# File Remove permission to different user in AIX

Tags: oracle, aix

Facts

1. My Server running on AIX
2. some files (to sftp) generate by Oracle and put in to a CBSINTERFACE directory
3. Different user created for sftp (lets say sftpusr) will access and get the files from CBSINTERFACE and remove the files after get.

Problem

sftpusr is unable to remove files since files generated by Oracle and aftpusr does not have write permission to those files.

what i did

I granted permission CBSINTERFACE directory but still files created by oracle cannot be removed by sftpusr

Requesting help to grant permission to sftpusr

Comment: Create a group called `sftpgroup`; add `sftpuser` into this group, and do this: `chgrp sftgroup /path/CBSINTERFACE; chmod g+ws /path/CBSFINTERFACE`

Answer (score 0):

> I granted permission CBSINTERFACE directory but still files created by oracle cannot be removed by sftpusr

Not sure what you did here, but sftpuser - which is presumably an operating system user and not a database user - must have write permissions to the directory through the operating system (not the database) since it interacts through the operating system. Permissions granted on a DIRECTORY object within the database only apply to database users.